# Socket.io is working on HTTP but not on HTTPS

Tags: node.js, ssl, express, https, socket.io

I am having a strange problem, while socket.io is working correctly on HTTP, its giving *404* error on HTTPS even while including:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js" />
```

Here is my express setup:

**HTTP**

```
var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
    console.log("Express server listening on port " + app.get('port'));
});
io = socketio.listen(server);
```

**HTTPS**

```
var httpsServer = https.createServer({
    key: privateKey,
    cert: certificate,
    ca: [c1, c2, c3],
    requestCert: true,
    rejectUnauthorized: false
}, app);

io = socketio.listen(server);

httpsServer.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
    console.log("Express server listening on port " + app.get('port'));
});
```

Except socket.io everything is working fine on HTTPS.

Comment: A typo? `socketio.listen(server);` -> `socketio.listen(httpsServer);`

Comment: @Varun Still it does not work after correct your mistake?

Comment: It started working after I fixed it (stupid typo)